# Unable to read Power BI.api NUPKG file from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dotnet-sdk

We are trying to install/Open Microsoft.Powerbi.api.4.16.0 NUPKG file from Visual Studio. It's throwing error - "The file is not displayed in the text editor because it's binary or uses unsupported text encoding". Screenshot attached herewith. Could you please help us resolve this issue.

[Error Message in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p5eU.png)
[Error Message in visual coder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfzjK.png)

Regards,
Kushal

we tried to install the file in visual studio, but its not allowing us.

could you please, us to resolve this issue.